# Is there a way to give better errors on std::conditional fail?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

Suppose I have a function:

```
template<typename T, typename Dummy =
                           typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,int>::type >
void foo(T var0, T var1);
```

This function is only created if `T` is some integral type. The only problem is that if I try to use it on a non integral type I get this huge error.

Is there any way to create a custom error string that happens in a similar scenario?

Comment: Actually, your example does not even work for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edfd2163b75a8b12

Comment: @BaummitAugen It will fail because doubles are not integral

Comment: I get that that's supposed to happen, but it does not happen with gcc and clang. Tbh, I'm not sure why. Might be worth an extra question if you care.

Comment: @Baum That's cause the example is wrong :). Needs `::type` for the `enable_if`, otherwise it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Barry Lol, thanks. Guess that is a "wake-up call" for me to go to bed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the Dummy trick and use `static_assert`, this is like a textbook usecase:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
void fun(T t){
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "fun requires integral");
}

int main(){
    fun(1);
    fun(2.);
}
```

fails with the quite clear message:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void fun(T) [with T = double]':
main.cpp:10:11:   required from here
main.cpp:5:5: error: static assertion failed: fun requires integral
     static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "fun requires integral");
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In some more or less distant future, 2020 or so, you can also use [concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) for this, there is an experimental implementation in gcc if you want to play around with that.